# Twitter bootstrap — подгрузка ajax информации в popover

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap, javascript

В Bootstrap есть возможность вставлять [Popovers](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers). Формат такой:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on left
</button>
```

Текст сообщения находится в  **data-content**. Как **правильнее** подгружать информацию в этот поповер  с помощью ajax? Ожидается довольно обширный html.

Answer (score 1):

там ниже написано api. Думаю, выглядеть будет примерно так

```
$('#myPopover').on('show.bs.popover', function () {
  $.ajax(... , function(data) {
       this.data('content',data);
  });
});
```